# Validation Message MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My code is as followed and the error message are not displayed:

Index.cshtml

```
@model WebApp.Models.OrderItems
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveToDB", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
{

@Html.Partial("Information")

}
```

Partial : Information.cshtml

```
@model WebApp.Models.OrderItems

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CLInfo.ClientName)</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CLInfo.ClientName, new { style = "width:250px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CLInfo.ClientName)
    </div>
</div>
```

Model :

```
public class OrderItems
 {
      public InfoCLInfo{ get; set; }
 }
```

Model : the class for Infos

```
public class Info
 {
     [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
     [Required]
     public string ClientName{ get; set; }    
 }
```

The controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "SaveToDB")]
    public ActionResult SaveToDB(OrderItems Client)
    {
      var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_db == null)
                _db = new OrderDB();

            OrderItems ClientOrig = Session["Clientobj"] as OrderItems;
            ClientOrig.CLInfo = Client.CLInfo;

            Session["Clientobj"] = null;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index (OrderItems Client)
    {
        int ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Client"]);
        if ClientID == 0)
        {
            ClientID = 2;
            Session["Client"] = ClientID;
        }

        if (Session["Clientobj"] == null)
        {
            Client = new OrderItems();
            Client.CLOrderID = 123;
            Session["Clientobj"] = Client;
        }
        else
        {
            Client = Session["Clientobj"] as OrderItems
        }
        return View(Client);
    }
```

on post the ModelState.IsValid return false which true, but I don't have any message to tell the user where is the error to be fixed.

I tried to add : @Html.ValidationSummary(true) after the BeginForm , but it didn

Any idea please

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the related controller code as well?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson related controller code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use RedirectToAction if you want to retain your model state.  All errors and what not are kept in the ModelState object, and when you redirect to action it's performing a new get action, which starts fresh with a clean slate.

You need to return the view like you do in the original action.

Comment: Exactly why I asked for the related controller code!

Comment: Thanks,f I put :  return View("Index"); in the Information.cshtml  the Model is null for :   `<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CLGInfo.Country, new SelectList(Model.CLInfo.Country, "idCountry", "Country"))
</div>`    the error message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @ProtoCUS - I will repeat myself.  You need to return the view *LIKE YOU DO IN THE ORIGINAL ACTION*, which means passing the model as well.  So you `return View("Index", Client)`